# How to export full Google Sheet tab as PDF and then print to local printer using Python

Tags: python, canvas, operating-system, pywin32, reportlab

After several weeks, I'm getting very close into solving my overall issue. I'm looking to connect my Google Sheet to a local printer & print the tabs "Label" and "Claims".  Label needs to be printed x times, x being defined by the value in cell f2.  Claims should be printed once as well.

This seems all taken care of, but for some reason the full Google Sheet tab isn't being exported to a PDF correctly.

It seems like the label is printing in portrait, when it should be landscape & the text maybe needs to be larger (image below how it is printing)?

[![Wrong Label][1]][1]

I can't seem to figure out how to adjust this. The "Claims" tab just prints blank, but I think it is the same issue for both.

Any thoughts on how I could adjust this code to fully print the tab?  Sample URL added:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MmUb7aPR9JVy-o2erbIDFzoY1iH9M5skcBRYNTuB_Ug/edit#gid=904472643

```
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import win32print
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A5
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

# Set up Google Sheets API credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Set up printer name and font
printer_name = "Rollo Printer"
font_path = "arial.ttf"

# Register Arial font
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', font_path))

# Open the Google Sheet and select Label and Claims worksheets
sheet_url = "URL"
label_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Label")
claims_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Claims")

# Get the number of label copies to print
num_copies = int(label_sheet.acell("F2").value)

# Set up label filename and PDF canvas
label_file = "label.pdf"
label_canvas = canvas.Canvas(label_file, pagesize=A5)

# Write label text to PDF canvas
label_text = label_sheet.get_all_values()
x_pos = 10  # set initial x position
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
line_height = 14  # set line height for text
label_canvas.setFont('Arial', 8)
for row in label_text:
    for col in row:
        textobject = label_canvas.beginText()
        textobject.setFont('Arial', 8)
        textobject.setTextOrigin(x_pos, y_pos)
        lines = col.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            textobject.textLine(line)
            y_pos -= line_height
        label_canvas.drawText(textobject)
        x_pos += 90
        y_pos = 260
    x_pos = 10

# Save the label PDF and print to the printer
label_canvas.save()
for i in range(num_copies):
    os.startfile(label_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)

# Set up claims filename and PDF canvas
claims_file = "claims.pdf"
claims_canvas = canvas.Canvas(claims_file, pagesize=A5)

# Write claims text to PDF canvas
claims_text = claims_sheet.get_all_values()
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
claims_canvas.setFont('Arial', 8)
for row in claims_text:
    textobject = claims_canvas.beginText()
    textobject.setFont('Arial', 8)
    lines = row[0].split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        textobject.textLine(line)
        y_pos -= line_height
    claims_canvas.drawText(textobject)
    y_pos = 260

# Save the claims PDF and print to the printer
claims_canvas.save()
os.startfile(claims_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)
```

I figured out switching to landscape, but the labels still do not look right. is there a way to designate them as 4x6? or export from Google Sheet differently? The issue is the tabs are not being exporting as a PDF the way they should be formatted for a 4x6 label.

```
 import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import win32print
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape, A5
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

# Set up Google Sheets API credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Set up printer name and font
printer_name = "Rollo Printer"
font_path = "arial.ttf"

# Register Arial font
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', font_path))

# Open the Google Sheet and select Label and Claims worksheets
sheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eRO-30eIZamB5sjBp-Mz2QMKCfGxV037MQO8nS7G7AI/edit#gid=1988901382"
label_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Label")
claims_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Claims")

# Get the number of label copies to print
num_copies = int(label_sheet.acell("F2").value)

# Set up label filename and PDF canvas
label_file = "label.pdf"
label_canvas = canvas.Canvas(label_file, pagesize=landscape(A5))

# Write label text to PDF canvas
label_text = label_sheet.get_all_values()
x_pos = 10  # set initial x position
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
line_height = 14  # set line height for text
label_canvas.setFont('Arial', 8)
for row in label_text:
    for col in row:
        textobject = label_canvas.beginText()
        textobject.setFont('Arial', 8)
        textobject.setTextOrigin(x_pos, y_pos)
        lines = col.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            textobject.textLine(line)
            y_pos -= line_height
        label_canvas.drawText(textobject)
        x_pos += 90
        y_pos = 260
    x_pos = 10

# Save the label PDF and print to the printer
label_canvas.save()
for i in range(num_copies):
    os.startfile(label_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)

# Set up claims filename and PDF canvas
claims_file = "claims.pdf"
claims_canvas = canvas.Canvas(claims_file, pagesize=landscape(A5))

# Write claims text to PDF canvas
claims_text = claims_sheet.get_all_values()
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
claims_canvas.setFont('Arial', 8)
for row in claims_text:
    textobject = claims_canvas.beginText()
    textobject.setFont('Arial', 8)
    lines = row[0].split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        textobject.textLine(line)
        y_pos -= line_height
    claims_canvas.drawText(textobject)
    y_pos = 260

# Save the claims PDF and print to the printer
claims_canvas.save()
os.startfile(claims_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)
```

I am thinking the code needs to look something more like this, but I'm receiving a traceback error (also below).

Code:

```
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import win32print
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape, portrait
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

# Set up Google Sheets API credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Set up printer name and font
printer_name = "Rollo Printer"
font_path = "arial.ttf"

# Register Arial font
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', font_path))

# Open the Google Sheet and select Label and Claims worksheets
sheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eRO-30eIZamB5sjBp-Mz2QMKCfGxV037MQO8nS7G7AI/edit#gid=1988901382"
label_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Label")
claims_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Claims")

# Get the number of label copies to print
num_copies = int(label_sheet.acell("F2").value)

# Set up label filename and PDF canvas
label_file = "label.pdf"
label_canvas = canvas.Canvas(label_file, pagesize=landscape((6*72*mm), (4*72*mm)))

# Write label text to PDF canvas
label_text = label_sheet.get_all_values()
x_pos = 10  # set initial x position
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
line_height = 20  # set line height for text
label_canvas.setFont('Arial', 18)
for row in label_text:
    for col in row:
        textobject = label_canvas.beginText()
        textobject.setFont('Arial', 18)
        textobject.setTextOrigin(x_pos, y_pos)
        lines = col.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            textobject.textLine(line)
            y_pos -= line_height
        label_canvas.drawText(textobject)
        x_pos += 145
        y_pos = 260
    x_pos = 10

# Save the label PDF and print to the printer
label_canvas.save()
for i in range(num_copies):
    os.startfile(label_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)

# Set up claims filename and PDF canvas
claims_file = "claims.pdf"
claims_canvas = canvas.Canvas(claims_file, pagesize=landscape((6*72*mm), (4*72*mm)))

# Write claims text to PDF canvas
claims_text = claims_sheet.get_all_values()
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
claims_canvas.setFont('Arial', 18)
for row in claims_text:
    textobject = claims_canvas.beginText()
    textobject.setFont('Arial', 18)
    lines = row[0].split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        textobject.textLine(line)
        y_pos -= line_height
    claims_canvas.drawText(textobject)
    y_pos = 260

# Save the claims PDF and print to the printer
claims_canvas.save()
os.startfile(claims_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\amadl\JRPrintFinal> & "C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe" c:/Users/amadl/JRPrintFinal/printerv7testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\amadl\JRPrintFinal\printerv7testing.py", line 34, in <module>
    label_canvas = canvas.Canvas(label_file, pagesize=landscape((6*72*mm), (4*72*mm)))
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: landscape() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUv4C.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[ReportLab.Docs]: Graphics and Text with pdfgen - More about the Canvas](https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch2_graphics/#more-about-the-canvas) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The `pagesize` argument **is a tuple of two numbers** in points (1/72 of an inch).

Pagesizes are specified as tuples, including the ones dynamically constructed (via functions: *e.g.*: *landscape*).
You can see such a function like a transformation from one page size (passed as an argument) to another (returned).

This can also be seen in the source code: [[ReportLab.HG]: hg-public/reportlab - (v3.5.0) src/reportlab/lib/pagesizes.py](http://hg.reportlab.com/hg-public/reportlab/file/cfcfe32848ff/src/reportlab/lib/pagesizes.py) (I'm not familiar with *Mercurial* so I don't know whether the *URL* is permanent (because of that *Id* it contains) or (if not,) for how long it will be valid).

So, you must change the faulty line to:

```py
label_canvas = canvas.Canvas(label_file, pagesize=landscape((6 * 72 * mm, 4 * 72 * mm)))
```

As an additional note, I don't know what the page dimensions should be, but the specified values look kind of wrong to me (especially because of that ***72*** factor - which represents the *DpI* - multiplied by the rest).

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for the tweak - it seems Adobe Reader doesn't proceed past the print preview window now though & I'm receiving this error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\amadl\JRPrintFinal\printerv7testing.py", line 66, in <module>
    claims_canvas = canvas.Canvas(claims_file, pagesize=landscape((6*72*mm), (4*72*mm)))
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: landscape() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

any thoughts?

Comment: could that be because 72 is incorrect? I'm going to do some digging and try to figure out what is needed

Comment: hey @KJ thanks for this, I think that helps -- I'm just a little unsure what should be replaced then.  Are you saying it should be pagesize=landscape((432,288))) ???? going to try that now.

Comment: apologies - super confused here, this brings back the original traceback about landscape only taking one positional argument; not sure I'm putting your edit into action correctly though, if there's any chance you wouldn't mind explaining more or giving an example that would be super helpful

Comment: The traceback from the comment indicates the same error, meaning you messed up the parentheses again (it's the original code). Also, you can get rid of the *landscape* function and pass the 2 values directly (in descending order). In your particular case you could replace: `... pagesize=(1224.5669291338584, 816.3779527559057)`.

Comment: Both of these are helpful, 1224.5669, 816.377 creates the same result but still works.  600,300 actually increases the size of the text which is helpful, but it's not printing the way it should.  The information on the tab in the same column is just overlapping. I'm going to try rigging it and putting it in different columns, even though a little weird. Any other suggestions are super helpful. These both help.

Comment: These actually work very well, im starting to think the issue is something else -- is anyone aware of a way to add text padding on the export? when I flip the cells to be move across the row, they space out on the label.  When they are vertical on the same column, they all get pushed together, even when there are spaces in between.

Comment: im having some success by editing the google sheet actually. i need to figure out the margins though

Comment: in an effort to not overload this question, I've accepted the answer -- I'm having trouble with the right and left margins, so I will post a new question. I'm getting close with bottomup but not working fully. Thank you both for your immense help. BTW setting pagesize to 300,100 works best for me